# No obtengo los datos del backend en Angular

Tags: angular, angular7

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Angular 7, y utilizo in-memory-web-api para la obtención de datos del backend. El servicio de la aplicación lo defino de la siguiente manera:

```
//Header options
httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
};

//extract function
private extractData(res: Response) {    
let body = res;
return body || {};
}

//get records function   
getFacturas(): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, this.httpOptions).pipe(
  map(this.extractData),
  catchError(this.handleError)
 );    
}
```

En el fake-backend-services, el metodo createDb devuelve un arreglo de registros de la siguiente manera:

```
return JSON.stringify(this.facturas);
```

Cuando realiza la petición, la vista me muestra el contenido vacío y obtengo el siguiente error en la consola:

Backend returned code 404, body was: undefined

Agradecería cualquier ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Alison el código que aportas es insuficiente para dar una respuesta acertada. Antes aclarar que un error 404 normalmente significa que no se a podido encontrar el recurso, ya sea por que no existe en la api o por que no existe la api(normalmente la url es incorrecta o el servido esta caído). Por lo que muestras creo que el problema pude ser por dos motivos.

El primero es que no tengas bien configurado in-memory-web-api, lo cual puedes leer todo acerca de ello [aquí](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api).

El segundo error puede estar aquí `return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, this.httpOptions).pipe(`, mas concretamente aqui `this.apiUrl` puede que no  estés escribiendo correctamente la url del recurso

Answer (score 1):

@Alber,

Revisando tus sugerencias, encontré la solución. Todo se trataba de leer cuidadosamente la configuración de in-memory-web-api. El objeto de arreglo que almacena los datos, debe llamarse de la misma forma que el endpoint de la petición:

```
//Este código pertenece al servicio
apiUrl = "/api"; //url base
const url = `${this.apiUrl}/facturas`; //facturas sería el endpoint
```

Mientras que en la función dB de in-memory-web-api, es imprescidible devolver el arreglo de facturas como un objeto de arreglo:

```
return {facturas};
```

Gracias por su colaboración.